# Progress Dialog in asyncTask OnPreExecute method Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have `MainActivity.java` Activity class which loads when application launches. I am using `asyncTask` methods in sperate file named `ServerOperation.java` . I need to show the progress bar in `onPreExecute` method of asyncTask. I am using following code but its not working and application crashes:

```
public class ServerOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Job>> {
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    MainActivity myActivity = new MainActivity();
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(myActivity.getApplicationContext(),"PLEASE WAIT","LOADING JOBS...", true);
}
}
```

How should I make progressDialog work on main activity?

Thanks.

Comment: Is MainActivity a Activity class (extends Activity)?

Comment: Please post the crash i.e logcat.

Comment: Yes MainActivity is activity class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **never create an instance of Acitvity class**. Its not a normal java class.

You can pass the Activity Context to the constructor of Asynctask

Invoke Aysnctask as

```
 new ServerOperation(MainActivity.this).execute(params);
```

in MainActivity

Then

```
 Context mContext;
 public ServerOperation (Context context)
 {
       mContext =context;

 }
```

Then

```
  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,"PLEASE WAIT","LOADING JOBS...", true);
```

Comment: @NidaSulheri you are welcome. just remember not to instantiate Activity class yourself. Its declared in manifest and it has a lifecycle

Comment: You send activity as parameter but you then assign it to context how? and no super() and override for constructor,proexecutepostexecute?

Comment: @Clara_57S activity extends from Context. You have constructor that takes context as a param there is no need for super http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/android/os/AsyncTask.java. You need to call super in onPreExecute and onPostExecute